# Where to call finish()?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, activity-finish

I am saving an event. When I click on save I want to check if title is not null and start time equals end time and dose event overlap and then save the event.

I have a boolean variable to check if edit mode is true. If it is true I want to update the existing event.

Now I tried to do this but when I am saving the event I want to check all these scenario and show the snackbar and then finish the activity.

1) But now the activity get finishes as soon as I click on save.

2) Also When I want to update it shows event exists.

What's wrong here?

```
  save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            eventTitle = title.getText().toString();
            location = mAutocompleteView.getText().toString();


            if (eventTitle.length() == 0) {

                showAlert("Title can not be empty.");

            }
            else if (startTime.equals(endTime)) {
                showAlert("End Time can not be same as Start Time.");
            }

            else if (db.doesEventOverlap(startTime,endTime,dayOfWeek)) {

               showAlert("Event Exists");

            }

            else {

                if (editMode) {

                eventData.setTitle(title.getText().toString());
                eventData.setFromDate(fromDate);
                eventData.setToDate(toDate);
                eventData.setDayOfWeek(selectDay.getText().toString());
                eventData.setLocation(mAutocompleteView.getText().toString());
                eventData.setNotificationTime(notificationTime);

                    db.updateEvent(eventData);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Event Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

               else {
                        db.addEvent(new EventData(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, dayOfWeek, location, notificationTime, mColor));
                        showAlert("Event Added.");
                }

                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```

dose event overlap function :

```
     boolean doesEventOverlap(String startTime, String endTime, String day) {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " = '" + day + "'" + " AND "

            + "(" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + startTime
            + "' AND '" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + endTime
            + "' AND '" + endTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + startTime
            + "' AND '" + endTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

            + " ('" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_FROM_DATE
            + " AND " + KEY_TO_DATE + " < '" + endTime + "')";


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            EventData event = new EventData();
            return cursor.getInt(0) > 0;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return false;
}
```

create table

```
  public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EVENTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_FROM_DATE + " DATE,"
            + KEY_TO_DATE + " DATE,"
            + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_NOTIFICATION_TIME + " DATE,"
            + KEY_COLOR + " TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
}
```

Thank you..

Edit :

show alert method for snack bar.

```
 public void showAlert(String alert){

    Snackbar.make(parentLayout, alert, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Don’t forget to show!

    Snackbar.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
            super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
            super.onShown(snackbar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide Your stacktrace.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Snackbar, you can use `Snackbar.Callback` interface to listen when the snackbar is dismissed, and then finish the activity.

Example:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(save, "Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
        snackbar.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
                super.onShown(snackbar);
            }
        });
```

EDITED:

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(parentLayout, alert, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

        snackbar.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onShown(Snackbar snackbar) {
                super.onShown(snackbar);
            }
        });

        snackbar.show(); // Don’t forget to show!
```

Comment: Its showing error non static method can not be referenced from static context.@Octaviano Putra

Comment: where dou you put this statement on?

Comment: I have created method for snackbar.Please check edited question.

Comment: setCallback is non-static method. so you must assign your created snackbar to a variable first, then call the setCallback method

Comment: Thank you.. this works.. But can you check my dose event overlap function? I want to update the event but it shows event exists and I want to check if event exists for saving an event. What's wrong with if else logic?@Octaviano Putra